# Need help aligning icons for my custom top bar

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

Basically I have a row of icons shown in my top bar as shown in the image below. I am unable to position them individually based on my expectation.

Tried using Flexible and Expanded widget to fill up the empty gap in the middle, but it doesn't work. Maybe i'm doing it wrongly

**What I got:**

[image]

**My expectation:**

I want the back arrow icon to align to the most left, where the starting alignment starts together with the heading text. The remaining three icons align to the end with even spacing. The heading below is another Container widget that has a child Column widget to show Heading and Subheading.

Ignore the opacity and streambuilder as it's for another purpose

```
Widget _topMenuBar(BuildContext context){
   return Container(
      height: 30.0,
      color: Colors.green.shade700,
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 20.0),
      margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10.0),
      child: new Row(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
        children: <Widget>[
          Flexible(
            flex: 6,
            child: Opacity(
                opacity: _opacityTween.evaluate(animation),
                child: FlatButton(
                  onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context),
                  child: new Icon(
                      Icons.arrow_back,
                      color: Colors.white,
                      size: 24.0
                  )
                ),
              ),
          ),
          Flexible(
            flex: 1,
            child: StreamBuilder<bool>(
              stream: someFunction(),
              builder: (context, snapshot){
                if(snapshot.hasData && snapshot.data){
                  return Opacity(
                    opacity: _opacityTween.evaluate(animation),
                    child: IconButton(
                      onPressed: () => {doSomething()},
                      icon: Icon(
                          Icons.star,
                          color: Colors.white,
                          size: 24.0),

                    )
                  );
                }
                return Opacity(
                  opacity: _opacityTween.evaluate(animation),
                  child: IconButton(
                    onPressed: () => {doSomething()},
                    icon: Icon(
                        Icons.star_border,
                        color: Colors.white,
                        size: 24.0)
                  ),
                );
              },
            ),
          ),
          Flexible(
            flex: 1,
            child: Opacity(
              opacity: _opacityTween.evaluate(animation),
              child: IconButton(
                onPressed: () => {doSomething()},
                icon: new Icon(
                  Icons.share,
                  color: Colors.white,
                  size: 24.0
                )
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Flexible(
            flex: 1,
            child:  Opacity(
              opacity: _opacityTween.evaluate(animation),
              child: IconButton(
                onPressed: () => print('more'),
                icon: new Icon(
                  Icons.more_vert,
                  color: Colors.white,
                  size: 24.0
                )
              ),
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
```

}

Comment: use the expanded widget in between first and second widget.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why don't you use AppBar? It does all the work for you.

Comment: @Linxy Because the default AppBar widget has its own UI design limitations. I wanna make my own custom appbar that has it's my own animations/transitions based on how i scroll the listview below and also flexibility of placement of widgets.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you need to make all four IconButtons same as each other. First Flexible is using FlatButton instead of IconButton, the rest 3 are ok.

```
Flexible(
        flex: 6,
        child: Opacity(
            opacity: _opacityTween.evaluate(animation),
            child: ***FlatButton*** ====>>> ***IconButton***(
              onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context),
              child: new Icon(
                  Icons.arrow_back,
                  color: Colors.white,
                  size: 24.0
              )
            ),
          ),
      ),
```

Comment: Thanks, can't believe it's because of this. It works fine now. :D